# treeviewer does not deselect the tree item

Tags: java, swt, jface

I wanted to create dynamic tree struture in my application.
There my requirement is When the user selects any tree node
and click insert the child should be inserted below the selected parent. That is working fine. Now the  problem is
i am unable to deselect the currently selected tree item in order to change tree item .
I clicked the background of the view and tried to insert
a new tree item, but still it goes to the previously selected tree node as still it highlight as the selected one. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you create a `TreeViewer` with style `SWT.SINGLE` then the tree will insist on keeping an item selected unless you explicitly clear the selection.

To clear a selection use:

```
treeViewer.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
```

If you use `SWT.MULTI` as the tree style you can clear the selection with Ctrl+Click